# Change speed of DC motor using A5950

Tags: dc-motor, motor-controller, motordriver

I want to change the rotation speed of a DC motor using a [A5950](https://www.allegromicro.com/-/media/files/datasheets/a5950-datasheet.pdf) driver.
Reading the datasheet I don't find anything explicit about how to change the speed.

Looking at Table 1:

[image]

my first thought was I can apply a PWM to pin `ENABLE` but it would switch between forward/reverse and *brake*, hence it is not the way.

So how I can control the speed?

Answer (score 1):

The speed depends linearly on the applied rotor voltage only in the idealized no-resistance and no magnetic saturation case. If we know how the induced voltage depends on the speed we can measure the motor current and take into the account the winding resistance with math. We can calculate the actual induced voltage and use the known induced voltage vs. speed dependency reversely. The motor is used as its own speed sensor. Still is needed a feedback controller which sets the input voltage for the wanted speed to prevent speed variations along mechanical load variations.

The principle is an old one, but varying brush resistance makes it inaccurate. Better to have a proper speed sensor - an optical one or AC generator. Without feedback controller there's no hope to get an accurate result.

Your motor controller is made to feed the available operating voltage, perform braking and limit the current with internal PWM, but there's no speed sensing at all. Any speed control must happen in the device which commands your A5950. It may happen by switching the voltage ON-OFF with the control signals. The internal current limiting PWM may be used for speed control by fooling the overcurrent protection externally (apply Vref, measure the sensed current and voltage for feedback). I skip it.

Answer (score 1):

Datasheet is a bit sketchy in not showing examples of use; the next step would be to refer to app notes or white papers, but a quick search doesn't show any.

Failing that, read and understand the datasheet ... in particular, the truth table on page 7, which seems to be all you get on the actual control pin function (since all the control inputs are helpfully labelled "control input" and that's it!)

Table 1 (page 7) shows the relation of the outputs to the inputs; read this carefully.

It appears that applying PWM to the "Enable" input will allow you to control the percentage time the outputs are active and thus (loosely) the motor speed.

Then the "Mode" pin allows you to choose between 2 quadrant (Mode = 1) and 4 quadrant (Mode = 0) operation; 4 quadrant operation actively slows the motor down while 2 quadrant would allow freewheeling (imagine a vehicle rolling downhill).

Speed will then be loosely related to the PWM duty cycle you apply to the Enable input. If you control that by a knob on a pot, you have "open loop control" which is crude and inaccurate. Better is "closed loop control" where you add a control circuit which measures the actual speed and adjusts the PWM duty cycle to correct errors; this is described in the other answer.